# Iterate trought struct in C

Tags: c, struct, bitmap

I am writing program in C. I would like to print out values of each element in struct, so that I can print out according value for each bitmap header member. Hence, is it possible to iterate trough each element of struct?

Also is it possible to get number of elements in struct if each element is different size?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in C. There is no iterator over data types. You have to print each field in your struct separately in your function.

Addition:
One way to do this on your own would be to use X-Macros as suggested by coderredoc. But it might get a bit nast for different data types to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in C. Use some thing called `X-macro` . Not exactly iterator over data types but a smart way out.

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Comment: why downvote? Reason please..Please give me the reason I will try to improve my answer

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but I think it's because it's *almost* a link-only answer, and those are frowned upon on SO (because of link rot). Might want to expand your answer.

Comment: @TimČas.: Thanks for reply..I was writing an explanation and thinking the solution ..( how to represent it in X-macros) then I saw it was a duplicate question..thats why I didnt add anything more because the answer was already there..but I will add an explanation though.

Comment: @TimČas.: I will notify you when I update this